# How to start deployed Angular application locally

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox

I have deployed Angular frontend, on server it working fine, there are 3 script

```
/runtime.0fad6a04e0afb2fa.js    
/polyfills.24f3ec2108a8e0ab.js    
/main.a9b28b9970fe807a.js
```

I want to start this application in Firefox, without IIS or Apache - by simple click to Html-page. Is it possible?

But Firefox said me

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///runtime.0fad6a04e0afb2fa.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

Is it possible to remove this restriction? Or Firefox never allow me loading and working this scripts?

Comment: Long story short: you can't. You need a web server to serve the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a CORS policy error, you need to run applications on an http-server like
[nodejs HTTP-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Comment: Thank you. I have in this machine IIS, it also can stored Angular app, I have check it -working correctly. But I was thinking - maybe it's possible to deny browser restriction and start Html-page directly? No, I understand.